# Searching 2 dimensional dictionary

Tags: python

I have a 2 dimensinal dictionary representing people.  Here's an example of it:

```
>>> people = {'pk1':{'firstname':'Brian', 'age':42}, 'pk2':{'firstname':'Alex',
'age':50}}
```

As can be seen, there is a primary key in each entry. Each one then points to a dictionary containing information about a specific person.  How do I search the overall 'people' dictionary to return me all people who have the age 42?

Comment: What result do you want? A list containing the primary key for each person matching the filter?  And are you looking for code to do this search one time, or for a reusable function which you can call from several places in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a more generic function that can perform various searches you can use something like:

```
def findPeople(people, filter):
    ret = {}
    for k, v in people.items():
        if filter(v):
            ret[k] = v
    return ret
```

Then for age == 42 you can call it like:

```
findPeople( people, lambda x: x['age'] == 42 );
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need primary key:

```
>>> [{id: value} for id, value in people.iteritems() if value['age'] == 42]
[{'pk1': {'age': 42, 'firstname': 'Brian'}}]
```

And if you don't:

```
>>> [value for value in people.itervalues() if value['age'] == 42]
[{'age': 42, 'firstname': 'Brian'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Generator_expressions).

```
>>> [p for p in people if people[p]['age'] == 42]
['pk1']
```

Comment: Nice and concise, but this would be a better answer if you explain why it's a good way to do things. Teach the original poster to fish, don't just give them one serving of fish.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you:

```
def search(primary, key, value):
    for secondary in primary.values():
        if secondary.get(key) == value:
            yield secondary
```

Example:

```
>>> for i in search(people, 'age', 42):
...      print(i)
{'firstname':'Brian', 'age':42}
```

A one line solution could be:

```
[secondary for secondary in people.values() if secodary.get('age') == 42]
```

**Note:** The use of `.get()` will allow you to search for a key even if that key is not present in every secondary dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Blunt method could look like this :

```
def find_in_dict(d, criterion, lookup):
    result = []
    for key, val in d.iteritems():
        if criterion in val and val[criterion] == lookup:
            result.append((key,val))
    return result

>>> people = {'pk1':{'firstname':'Brian', 'age':42}, 'pk2':{'firstname':'Alex', 'age':50}}
>>> find_in_dict(people, 'age', 42)
```

You can change the result formatting depending on your need to have the person's key or not.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are excellent and should do what you asked.

I'm assuming it's from a database, and that you are not doing this query in the database directly because you need different angles on the same data? If so, you may be able to get equally efficient results by using a smart system like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). If you don't actually need to do various interactions, I would recommend getting the data from the database directly since they are already made to do this kind of thing efficiently.

Comment: I am reading in a bunch of test results from an XML file.  I make up the primary from things like test class, test name.  I then need to do searches such on getting which ones passes and which ones failed. Thanks.